# Getting a list of strings from a parent's children

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Parents and Children, and Children have Names.  I'm trying to get a List of strings from a Parent that contains the Names of each of a given Parent's Children.  Something like:

```
List<string> Names = Parent.Children.Foreach(child => "add child.name to array");
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What list of strings are you trying to get from Parent? What is Parent? What is condition of selection? How does question relates to all these asp.net frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use select

```
List<string> Names = Parent.Children.Select(child => child.Name).ToList();
```